# Definition of "".Split(',')

Tags: language-agnostic

If I have a string with a comma-separated list of things and split it at the comma, I get an array:

```
"A,B,C,D".Split(',') = ["A","B","C","D"]
```

If I have a string without a comma, it is a single-element array:

```
"A".Split(',') = ["A"]
```

But there are two possible definitions what could happen when you try to split an empty string:

```
"".Split(',') = [""]
"".Split(',') = []
```

From my limited experience, the latter makes more sense, but I have not seen any language implement it; the common norm is the former. Is this just inherited/legacy behaviour or am I missing the deeper sense behind the first possibility?

Comment: This does not really make sense as a language-agnostic question.  There may be languages where the behavior you seem to prefer make sense; though from a general string-processing perspective, the difference between an empty string and no string is significant, and must be distinguishable. This also depends on how the language defines its string concept, and its general type system.

Comment: @tripleee Well, now that you say it, I guess I only know that it's like this in PHP, C#, ObjectPascal, Java and JavaScript. If object-oriented, null.Split(',') will throw a NullPointer error, which should be enough to distinguish between no string and empty string. I have to admit that I don't know about Ruby, Python, Perl, BASIC, COBOL or APL, though...

Comment: For all of those, I would say that the only difference between `"A".split(",")` and `"".split(",")` is the number of characters in the string, and returning the string itself makes perfect sense, and more so than not returning a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will give you empty string unless you use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries.

So it's upto us how we use it.

Comment: Thank you for adding this C#-specific find; so Microsoft also thinks that this issue is debatable, and I don't feel alone anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This may be debatable, but imo the first option should be correct because the array values are part of the string between two delimiters (and string margins of course).

So basically you parse string until you get to the first delimiter, set the value, continue parsing (and repeat).

This way, if you parse a string with no delimiters, the first element of the array will be the string. (your "A".split() case). Extrapolating to the empty string, the first element of the array should be an empty string. This ensures result consistency (always the result will be an array with at least an element).

So... I don't think is legacy, I think it is the way it should work.

Comment: And it's consistent with the operations `",".Split(',')` and `",,".Split(',')`, since there is no way for a sequence to have both zero and more than zero elements simultaneously.